# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror, nonetype

I am really new in Python, so I'm facing this issue:

```
#!venv/bin/python
import sys
import requests
import bs4

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
# If arguments are satisfied store them in readable variables
   url = 'http://%s' % sys.argv[1]
   file_name = sys.argv[2]

print('Grabbing the page...')
# Get url from command line
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

# Retrieve all links on the page
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')

file = open(file_name, 'wb')
print('Collecting the links...')
for link in links:
    href = link.get("href") + '\n' 
    file.write(href.encode())
file.close()
print('Saved to %s' % file_name)

else:

print('Usage: ./collect_links.py www.example.com file.txt')
```

I am getting this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Any helps, please?

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, the best we can do is guess ... but ... I'd guess that you've got an `<a>` that does not have an `href` attribute, which means `link.get("href" + '\n')` returns `None`, and `None` doesn't have an `encode()` method.

Comment: This error almost always means one of two things: (a) you called some function that always returns `None`, like `list.reverse`, or (b) you called some function that usually returns a value but returns `None` when there is no value to get, like many `find`-type functions.

Comment: From the traceback (which you didn't show us—please do in the future—but I can guess), the error comes from the `file.write(href.encode())` line, so it's either `file` or `href` that's `None`. Since the error message is about `encode` rather than `write`, it must be `href`. So now, you just need to figure out what function you called to get `href`. If you don't understand why that function can return `None`, read the docs, and it'll probably explain. So then you just have to figure out what to do with those cases.

Comment: Nice, well, I made a little change, so I believe is href is returning none

Comment: for link in links:
            href = link.get('href') + '\n'
            file.write(href.encode())
        file.close()

Comment: I got this error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' something to do with the + string!

Comment: Guys now the error changed it to TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' still not figuring out why!

Comment: To be able to recreate this, we would need some example for how you run the script, i.e. the URL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I include this line :
 href = "{0}\n".format(link.get("href"))

Thank you, guys!